# make displaytag work when javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, displaytag

i understand that displaytag library uses javascript extensively. my question is: is there a way to bypass that and make it work when the javascript is disabled in the browser. 
if there isn't, is there any other library that does what displaytag does (create a sortable/paginated table) without using any javascript. thank you.

Comment: Any other JavaScript library that does that *without* using any JavaScript? Hm, I would say no `:)` You'll need a server-side script...

Answer (score 1):

you can put a normal table inside
`<noscript></noscript>` tags

Answer (score 1):

No, if JavaScript is disabled by the user you won't be able to force it to work.  To get the same functionality, you could use an anchor for the column headers which loads another page where the column is sorted as required.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your first question: No. That would be stupid if web developers were allowed to bypass the user deciding to disable Javascript.

You could use something like Flash or similar to create a sortable table, I'm not aware of any non-JS / plugin solution for allowing the user to dynamically sort a table.